# How to position an absolute element on the top of the screen in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to position a Pressable to detect presses all over my Screen, but I can only place it inside the parent when I use top: 0, left: 0 as the style.

I use it inside a Component to create a pop-up menu, so I can't just put it inside the top View.

How can I make it fill the whole screen?

Comment: Try giving it height and width